# Having difficulty with Flow and Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-flow

Having problem with `Flow`. I have a simple app that updates a database. However, the update is not reflected in the UI. The database is updated, and when I restart the app, the UI will have the new value.

- `@Dao` code

```kotlin
@Query("SELECT * FROM schedule")
fun getSchedule(): Flow<Schedule>

@Update(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
suspend fun updateSchedule(schedule: Schedule)
```

- `Repository` code

```kotlin
val schedule: Flow<Schedule> = scheduleDao.getSchedule()

suspend fun updateSchedule(schedule: Schedule) {
    scheduleDao.updateSchedule(schedule = schedule)
}
```

- `viewModel` code

```kotlin
var schedule = repository.schedule.stateIn(
    initialValue = initialSchedule,
    scope = viewModelScope,
    started = WhileSubscribed(1000)
)

// update schedule code
fun updateSchedule(schedule: Schedule) {
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
        repository.updateSchedule(schedule = schedule)
    }
}
```

- inside the `Composable` element

```kotlin
val schedule by viewModel.schedule.collectAsState()
```

The `Schedule` object is updated from an **alert dialog**, by calling the `viewModel`s *updated* method. but the UI does not show the updated `Schedule` values.

Comment: Isn't it because of `started = WhileSubscribed(1000)`? What does it do?

Comment: `WhileSubscribed` delays when the flow is canceled.  In this case, it will wait 1000 ms.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Compose, but I'm pretty sure you'll need to share more of your Compose code to see how you're using this state. I think you're supposed to use `remember`. See the "Safe Flow collection in Jetpack Compose" [section here](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/a-safer-way-to-collect-flows-from-android-uis-23080b1f8bda#:~:text=Safe%20Flow%20collection%20in%20Jetpack%20Compose%20The%20Flow.collectAsState,State%3CT%3E%20to%20be%20able%20to%20update%20Compose%20UI.).

Comment: I'm not sure if it has anything to do with Compose, try collecting `schedule` in your view model and see if it outputs new values.

Comment: You can debug by adding `.onStart(println)` and `.onEach(println)` to your `StateFlow` in the ViewModel. Just to make sure the Flow is emitting.

Comment: I think the problem is with the `AlertDialog`.  I am just `Flow.collect{ }` within `LaunchedEffect` whenever, the `AlertDialog` State Changes.